# issues in coding programs without a user "save"

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a (relatively) novice programmer working in Python and Tkinter. The GUI app I'm building has many input fields, and all the data ultimately needs to end up in a file.

I'm wondering about the wisdom of trying to build this without a "save" button, so that it would operate like, say, Google Docs, in which the saving seems to happen more-or-less continuously. I'm worried about my (relatively computer-phobic) users assuming things are being saved to the file as they change various menu entries.

Specifically: is that just done via a background process saving every few seconds, with a save forced if the user tries to close between the auto-saves? Does one try to trigger the saves more intelligently than that? What are the issues?

Comment: Perhaps you could save the changes since the last saved version of the file in a delta file, similar to something like a git diff. Then just save that periodically. But I'm not sure, I'm interested in the answer as well.

Comment: You could consider adding save functionality to the buttons that the users will use to navigate around your application. At the end of the day I would recommend experimenting and seeing if you find one way that works best and doesn't affect the performance of your application too much. (Though if you are just saving a file it is unlikely to hamper anything by much.)

Comment: This would be a good use of a thread. You could have a thread running a "saving  method" every 25 seconds or so. But a save button even with that feature is a nice addition.

Comment: Consider that a save button will give users more confidence that your stuff is saved. I was always unnerved is google docs just closing out the window. I know that I'm probably good, but I'd like to be able to hit save just for my own comfort.